# Predict the missing number in this sequence

Tags: pattern

What number is missing in the sequence below?

27 3 119 34 124 93 145 116 235 ___ 295 354

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is 235

Factoring prime numbers and finding the derived pattern from one of the factors was the key

> I found largest prime factor multiplied by an integer starting with 1 and increasing by one for each of the subsequent numbers largest prime factors. The largest prime factor of 27 is 3 which starts the pattern:
>  3x1 = 3, 17x2 = 34, 31x3 = 93, 29x4 = 116, 47x5 = **235**, 59x6 = 354

Comment: explain where you get 47 from.

Comment: @Jasen 235 has the prime factors 5 and 47, of which 47 is the largest.

Comment: ah, from the 235 before the blank. that makes sense.